# RadAsyncUpload.click() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, telerik

I am trying to use to trigger a click event of the RadAsyncUpload select button.

```
var logoSelect = $('#logoUpload, .upload-logo');
var logoUploader = $telerik.$("#logoUploader");

logoSelect.click(function (e) {
    if (logoUploader) {
        logoUploader.click();
    }
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

There are two separate buttons #logoUpload and .upload-logo that should be triggering this event. I am able to reach the if statement and I am even able to capture the RadAsyncUpload object. However, the click event does not work.

Is there any way for me to do this? This works with regular ASP FileUpload but I would like to make this work for RadAsyncUpload.

EDIT: Here is the RadAsyncUpload markup

```
<telerik:RadAsyncUpload ID="logoUploader" runat="server" MultipleFileSelection="Disabled" PostbackTriggers="saveCustom"></telerik:RadAsyncUpload>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could trigger the click by its class

```
var logoUploader = $(".ruFileInput");
```

[Source](http://www.telerik.com/forums/how-to-hide-select-button-in-asyncupload#nW-b_jsXvkKUSZYMrjnNzQ)